# How to move a div up and down infinitely in CSS3?

Tags: css, css-animations

Hello I am trying to do the simple task of moving a div up and down to give a floating/hovering effect using bottom instead of top. So from `bottom: 63px` to `bottom: 400px`.

I am new to CSS and keyframes! As you can probably tell But here is what I have tried and it didn't seem to do anything:

```
.piece-open-space #emma {
    background-image: url('images/perso/Emma.png?1418918581');
    width: 244px;
    height: 299px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 244px;
    background-image: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 2149px;
    bottom: 63px;
    -webkit-animation: MoveUpDown 50s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes MoveUpDown {
    from {
        bottom: 63px;
    }
    to { 
        bottom: 400px;
    }
}
```

**Update**

The problem is it won't loop with is the goal I am looking for it gets to 400px then instantly goes back to 63px how would i make it get to 400px and then go back down to 63px it give the effect of an endless loop of "hovering/floating".

Comment: @diogo What do you mean "because of conflict"? What conflict are you solving with that edit?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You can adjust the timing of the `@keyframes` as follows:

```css
.object {
  animation: MoveUpDown 1s linear infinite;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

@keyframes MoveUpDown {
  0%, 100% {
    bottom: 0;
  }
  50% {
    bottom: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="object">
  hello world!
</div>
```

**EDIT**

As pointed out in a comment below using `transform` is preferred for [high performance animations](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/).

```css
.object {
  animation: MoveUpDown 1s linear infinite;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

@keyframes MoveUpDown {
  0%, 100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-100px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="object">
  hello world!
</div>
```

Comment: Don't use margin or top, bottom, etc cause it consumes cpu power very much as compared to using `transform: translate...` and ur animation can be slow on some low-end computers.

Answer (score 51):

Up/Down with **animation**:

```css
div {
    -webkit-animation: action 1s infinite  alternate;
    animation: action 1s infinite  alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes action {
    0% { transform: translateY(0); }
    100% { transform: translateY(-10px); }
}

@keyframes action {
    0% { transform: translateY(0); }
    100% { transform: translateY(-10px); }
}
```

```html
<div>&#8595;</div>
```

Comment: How to do the same, but also have the arrow move both along X and Y axis?

Answer (score 5):

Up and Down:

```
div {
        -webkit-animation: upNdown 2s infinite linear;
        animation: upNdown 2s infinite linear;
    }
@-webkit-keyframes upNdown {
         0% { }
         50% { transform: translate(-5px); }
         100% { }
    }
@keyframes upNdown {
         0% { }
         50% { transform: translate(-5px); }
         100% { }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to add `animation-direction: alternate;` (or `-webkit-animation-direction: alternate`) to your style rules on `.piece-open-space #emma`.

That should give you that floating-up-and-down-effect.

I.e. your css should look like:

```
.piece-open-space #emma {
    background-image: url('images/perso/Emma.png?1418918581');
    width: 244px;
    height: 299px;
    display: block;
    background-image: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 2149px;
    bottom: 63px;
    -webkit-animation: MoveUpDown 50s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just use `animation: up-down 1s infinite alternate;`

```
@keyframes up-down {
  from {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(8px);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to move a `div` up and down using CSS. Here is a short code snippet that helps you to move the selected `div` up and down.

Also, I would recommend creating two files - one `index.html` and another `style.css` and separate the code into two files and use it that way.

```css
/* Styling for the moving div */
.moving-div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: green;
    position: relative;
    animation: moveUpDown 3s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

/* Keyframes animation for up-down movement */
@keyframes moveUpDown {
    0% {
        top: 100px;
    }
    100% {
        top: 200px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="moving-div"></div>
```

Comment: Based on the URL of your link containing your user name/profile site, you appear to have linked to your own site/a site you're affiliated with. If you do, you *must* disclose that it's your site in your post. If you don't disclose affiliation, it's considered spam. See: [What signifies "Good" self promotion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212), [some tips and advice about self-promotion](/help/promotion), [What is the exact definition of "spam" for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260638), and [What makes something spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035).

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on [edit] and add some words summarising how your code addresses the question, or perhaps explain how your answer differs from the previous answer/answers. Thanks